# Double slash in assets URLs - 404 error in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess

site: https://opalschool.org/

I'm seeing a lot of 403 errors on a site of mine, and I see JavaScript errors in Google Developer Tools console that always show a double forward slash in different plugin URLs:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
>   https://opalschool.org/wp-content/plugins/wp-smush-pro//assets/shared-ui/wdev-ui.css?ver=1.0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
>   load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload&ver=6c00de4……:9 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

When I am viewing the admin page for Smush Pro I get the above errors, and the editing buttons are not available... this makes sense since the double slash is keeping some assets from loading. I've tested and removing the double slash before the assets/ folder reveals the files are there.

I see the same thing happen for some other plugins too (learndash), and I just installed WP Smush Pro on this site today. So I know the issue has been happening for a bit.

I have tried the following with no success:

- changing the `.htaccess` file
- re-saving permalinks
- turning off redirect related plugins
- searching the database for " //assets/" in links to try to change any that may have been written incorrectly but were lingering

I have a staging site copy of the live site that is a recent copy in the last few days, and it does not show the errors. I have tried comparing plugins on both sites and not found any causes. I may get further with this comparison, but haven't had that much time on it yet.

Answer (score 0):

JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1  -

WordPress uses the jQuery migrate script to ensure backwards compatibility for any plugins or themes you might be using which use functionality removed from newer versions of jQuery.

First try to deactivate all you plugins
Then activate one plugin and check it whether it is showing error or not 
Repeat this for all you plugins then you will able to find which plugin is creating this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The removing plugins troubleshooting method didn't provide results.

I believe now it may have been due to running the Hummingbird plugin from WPMUDEV. WPMUDEV has indicated it could be due to their plugin, and they said they'd roll out  a fix with the next version if it is.

WPMUDEV pointed to a spot in the code to remove the "/" that seemed to be causing the issue in the Smush Pro plugin's path to the assets folder. That fixed the issues with the Smush admin area not showing it's settings toggles. The only other plugin affected seems to be LearnDash, but so far I haven't figured out where to edit out a slash to fix the assets path and remove the error from the console.